# Construct class for gdal open

Tags: python, image, class, gdal

I an very new to python (2.6) and have a simple function to open geotif using gdal. It returns image array and image size (x,y).

```
def gdal_open(raster_file):

    if type(raster_file) is str and os.path.isfile(raster_file):
        gd_img = gdal.Open(raster_file)
        img_x = gd_img.RasterXSize # column
        img_y = gd_img.RasterYSize # row
        img = gd_img.ReadAsArray(0, 0, img_x, img_y)

    elif type(raster_file) is str and not os.path.isfile(raster_file):
        raise IOError

    return img, img_x, img_y
```

I want to convert this to class to get img, img.x and img.y as outputs. Can somebody help me?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the class its name is IMG

`class IMG:`

```
def __init__(self,path):
    if type(path)==str and os.path.isfile(path):
        self.path=path
        self.Raster=gdal.Open(path)
    elif type(path)==str and not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise IOError

def X(self):
    return self.Raster.RasterXSize

def Y(self):
    return self.Raster.RasterYSize

def RasterArray(self):
    return self.Raster.ReadAsArray()
```

and to use it

filepath="path/raster_name.tif"

raster=IMG(filepath)

xsize=raster.X()

ysize=raster.Y()

array=raster.RasterArray()

Comment: Awesome! So I had to make individual functions for x, y and image array. Thanks a lot!